# Can send Google Analytics events using gtag from my Node.js express server?

Tags: google-analytics, server, analytics-events, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

Currently I have a kind of complex server error logging system that I would to refactor in order to Google Analytics.

Is there a way to do something like this on my Node.js express server?

```
// INSTANTIATE THE gtag SOMEHOW

gtag("event", "server_error", {
  error_msg: "SOME ERROR MSG",
  path: req.path
});
```

I'm using Google Analytics 4 and I'm sending data using `gtag`.